# NodeJS emulate browser for get/post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

There's a lot of mixed results when I search around for emulating a browser.  Long story short, I need my Node server to do get & post requests.  Usually I'd just do this with the http package.  However, there is some anti-scripting things in place on the other side. Namely javascripts that let the server know it's a real browser. So, I need these to be executed.

I actually solved this problem like 5 years ago, but my site was only using PHP then.  The solution involved using a Qt webkit widget, and a fake X-server.  Not elegant, but it was pretty easy to do.  The only javascript engines I found available in Perl, PHP, or Python at the time were crazy slow.

As NodeJS is built on V8, I gotta think there's an easy way to do this.  For the record, I'm hoping to get something a la the following.

```
// Omitting some callbacks
http.get('http://remote.site', function(res) {
  res.on('end', function() {
      // previously accumulated data is the page returned by
      // the request.  Any thing found in a <script> tag would have
      // been executed.
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As NodeJS is built on V8, I gotta think there's an easy way to do this.

Actually, no!  There's a lot more to running in the context of a browser than simply being able to execute JavaScript.  All of the DOM stuff and what not is no present in Node.js.  Node.js has the JavaScript engine only.

Without the browser engine, you won't know what scripts to load, in what order, or be able to provide everything that comes with the `document` or `window`, which is likely a required part of what you're trying to do.

> The solution involved using a Qt webkit widget, and a fake X-server. Not elegant, but it was pretty easy to do.

This is actually the right solution... mostly.  Fortunately these days there are existing tools which have optimized this reasonably well.

Take a look at PhantomJS.  http://phantomjs.org/  You can write scripts for it much in the same way you do Node.js.  (It supports `require()` and what not, and most of the NPM packages you'd want work.)  PhantomJS will allow you to run the page and pull the DOM contents out easily.

In the event PhantomJS' built in JavaScript environment doesn't contain some Node.js component you need (for filesystem or network access for example), you can always control PhantomJS from your Node.js application.  https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response.  I will give PhantomJS a shot!